# list a map object in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, dictionary

## Example

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
list(map(f,[x for x in range(3)]))
```

## Q1:

How does `list` automatically iterates over the map object? What's actually going on here?

## Q2:

Since `list` is a `class` and a map object is an `iterator`, so does this mean that whenever a class acts on an iterator, it will always automatically iterates over the iterator?

### Can anyone help me out here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cooked up the example myself, so I know what the code means. For Q1, I'm just curious about why `list` can automatically iterate over the map object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The [`list` initializer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2638) delegates to [`list.extend()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L817) if it is passed an iterable.
2. No. This behavior is specific to sequence types.

Answer (score 1):

The map function is actually a powerful tool for speed. It is no different in functionality than a for loop.

The map function is written to execute directly by C code - hence making it run faster than if it were executed by interpreted python code. It works with any function (first param) and iterable (second param).

```
list(map(f,[x for x in range(3)])) # [0, 1, 4]
```

is the same as..

```
for x in range(3):
    f(x)
```

You can use a lambda expression as well. This would produce the same results as your function, without declaring the function:

```
list(map(lambda f: (f ** 2), [x for x in range(3)])) # [0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but that's not for the questions I'm asking.

Comment: You asked how the map function works in the first question, and my response is just that! The second one confused me, and it probably where the disconnect is. No worries, my bad. Good luck!